# Error while freeing double pointer in C

Tags: c, memory, free, genetic-algorithm

I'm writing code for a genetic algorithm, and I'm stuck at a point where I can't free unused memory. This is my main() code:

```
    szChromosomes = initial_population(&data[0]);
while (iCurrentGen <= data->m_iMaxGenerations)
{
    arrfSelectedChromosomes = selection(&data[0], szChromosomes);
    iSelectedLen = order_descending_grid(arrfSelectedChromosomes);
    szAuxGen = crossover(&data[0], arrfSelectedChromosomes, szChromosomes);
    free_generation(&data[0], szChromosomes);//Error line
    szChromosomes = szAuxGen;
    szAuxGen = NULL;
}
```

initial_population(&data[0]) creates the szChromosomes array (which I try to free later) like this:

```
char** initial_population(struct INPUT_DATA* d)
{
int i, j = 0;
float fMember = 0.0;
char** szChromosomes = (char**)malloc(d->m_iPopulationSize * sizeof(char*));

srand(time(NULL));
for (i = 0; i < d->m_iPopulationSize; ++i)
{
    szChromosomes[i] = (char*)malloc(d->m_iBitsPChromosome * sizeof(char));
    for (j = 0; j < d->m_iBitsPChromosome; ++j)
    {
        szChromosomes[i][j] = rand_1_0(0.0, 1.0) == 1? '1' : '0';
    }
    szChromosomes[i][j] = '\0';
}

return szChromosomes;
```

}

When I call the free_generation function, the For loop below gets executed:

```
    int i;

for (i = 0; i < d->m_iPopulationSize; ++i)
{
    free(szChromosomes[i]);
}

free(szChromosomes);
szChromosomes = NULL;
```

When the first call to free(szChromosomes[i]); takes place, I get the following error:

HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: after normal block (#99). CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer.

Comment: Try `(char*)malloc(d->m_iBitsPChromosome + 1);`. You need an extra character for `'\0'` in the end. Multiplication by `sizeof(char)` is redundant as `char` defined by the standard to have a size of 1 byte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char** initial_population(struct INPUT_DATA* d)
{
int i, j = 0;
float fMember = 0.0;
char** szChromosomes = (char**)malloc(d->m_iPopulationSize * sizeof(char*));

srand(time(NULL));
for (i = 0; i < d->m_iPopulationSize; ++i)
{
    szChromosomes[i] = (char*)malloc(d->m_iBitsPChromosome * sizeof(char));
    for (j = 0; j < d->m_iBitsPChromosome; ++j)
    {
        szChromosomes[i][j] = rand_1_0(0.0, 1.0) == 1? '1' : '0';
    }
    szChromosomes[i][j] = '\0';
}

return szChromosomes;
```

You insert a '\0' at the end of each string szChromosomes[i] but only use malloc with a length of d->m_iBitsPChromosome

So you try to write too far in the memory. To change that just change your 2nd malloc to:

```
szChromosomes[i] = (char*)malloc((d->m_iBitsPChromosome + 1) * sizeof(char));
```

Comment: That was the problem an extra byte for the \0 character! I can't believe I missed it by that much! thank you guys!

Answer (score 1):

```
szChromosomes[i][j] = '\0';
```

this line writes to memory you do not own.

For eg. take this example

```
char * p;
p = malloc(2);
p[0] = 'a';
p[1] = 'b';
```

You should not be doing

```
p[2] = '\0'
```

after this because you have allocated only 2 bytes, but you are writing to 3 bytes.

You can fix this 2 ways

1. Do you need the '\0'. Unless, you are going to use one of the functions from `<string.h>` which expects a '\0' to check the end, you need to terminate it by '\0'. In your own code which traverses the array, you can traverse using a for loop which ends at `ctr < d->m_iBitsPChromosome`.
2. Or you can allocate `malloc(d->m_iBitsPChromosome + 1)`